# How to integrate an Admin Theme in CakePHP2 Framework?

Tags: cakephp, themes, integration

We have bought an admin theme from Themeforest for our web application, which is being built using **CakePHP2 framework**. I know the basic way of integrating this theme into the **cakephp framework**, where we put the respective `JS, CSS files` under webroot folder and create layout to includes these files.

This method does give me desired results but I feel this is not the best way to integrate a theme in a **MVC** architecture. Because it does not work always for example, if i want to use just a look and feel of the downloaded theme and use Cakephp's pagination method it does not work seemlessly and i then need to keep tweaking the UI. Thus, I think there must be a best practice to integrate such themes. Can anyone suggest me if there is any better way of doing this integration?

I tried to search for such articles on the internet but did not find any suitable ones.Can you point me to one if you know or suggest any better way?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have integrated your purchased theme correctly.

Because the theme you purchased was not created as as CakePHP theme, the CSS is unlikely to match. This is what is causing your issue with some features not displaying correctly, such as CakePHP's pagination... the pagination helper ads HTML to the view in CakePHP that will more than likely not be covered by your **general** html theme.

For any instances you find that do not look like you expect, you will have to manually add CSS to your themes CSS file, or if your lucky just rename the CSS styles already in place.

Sorry, there is no easy way to fix this except manually integrating the missing CSS/HTML.

Good luck.